# django context processor form not showing errors when submitting

Tags: python, django, forms

I`m using *context processor* to render form to the base template in my project and the form seems to work ok, except it doesnt show any errors for required fields being blank and etc. The page is simply reloaded even if fields are not filled in.

I used this approach in other project before, and it worked just fine, but now I cant really figure out what happened and why it is like so.

Here is my *forms.py*:

```
from django import forms

class VersionSelectorForm(forms.Form):
    mode = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
                             choices=(('live', 'Live'), ('history', 'History')),
                             initial='live',
                             required=True,
                             help_text='Required')
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
                           required=True,
                           help_text='required')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(VersionSelectorForm, self).clean()
        mode = cleaned_data.get('mode')
        date = cleaned_data.get('date')

        if mode == 'history' and not date:
            msg = 'Date should be picked if \'History\' mode selected'
            self.add_error('date', msg)
```

*view.py*:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import VersionSelectorForm

def select_version(request): 
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = VersionSelectorForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            print('I am valid')
            mode = form.cleaned_data["mode"]
            date = form.cleaned_data["date"]
            if mode == "History":
                request.session['selected_date'] = date
            else:
                request.session['selected_date'] = None
    else: 
        form = VersionSelectorForm() 
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

*context_processors.py*:

```
from .forms import VersionSelectorForm 

def VersionSelectorFormGlobal(request): 
    return {'version_selector_form': VersionSelectorForm()}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from diagspecgen import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^select_version/$', views.select_version, name='select_version'),
]
```

*snippet from base.html*:

```
<section><div>
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'select_version'%}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ version_selector_form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div></section>
```

and of course I have added `'diagspecgen.context_processors.VersionSelectorFormGlobal'` to *context_processors* list in *settings.py*.

Looking forward for any help and thanks in advance for that.

Comment: It always redirects because that's what you do in your view: you always redirect, whether or not the form is valid.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for your reply Deniel. Can you, please, explain a little more better about this case. Reason, why I`m asking is that exactly this approach worked with another project, the only difference was that the form has been built straight from model in Meta class of form. Now something weird is going on.

Comment: There is nothing to explain. You have a redirect at the end of your view, and no other returns anywhere else, so the redirect is always called. This has nothing to do with models or Meta.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok, but why these dynamic messages are not shown when form fields are blank, as I know and understand, validation message should appear and page will not be reloaded at least until 'novalidate' argument is passed to 'form' tag.

Comment: But messages will only appear if you render a template with them in. And you're not, because once again **you're always redirecting**.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok, will try later to render form to some template, but really dont understand why this approach worked for ModelForm and I was able to see validation messages. I thought this is a sence of using form with context processor, that you can use it in such places as base, footer, header, etc. Anyway, thanks for help

Comment: **It didn't work** for your other form. You certainly have different code, probably including rendering the template in your view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman do u have few minutes just to take a look fo that proj? Maybe Im really blind, and cant find that point which cause to this, but I checked few times and didnt find difference in approaches, if u have a possibility, please github.com/godis-michael/WCUB thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not use context processor to render your form, but instead pass it to the django shortcut `render` function.

You could do something like this:

```
def select_version(request): 
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = VersionSelectorForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            print('I am valid')
            mode = form.cleaned_data["mode"]
            date = form.cleaned_data["date"]
            if mode == "History":
                request.session['selected_date'] = date
            else:
                request.session['selected_date'] = None
    else: 
        form = VersionSelectorForm() 
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

Don't forget the import  `from django.shortcuts import render`

Link to the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: Unfortunatelly this not working, Im trying to render form to base template, from which few more will be extended, so render is not suitable here. The most weird staff is that absolutely same code worked fine for other project, the only difference was that here form is not connected with model.

Comment: well, imho if you want to display the form, you need to render it ;)

Comment: and as @DanielRoseman said in his comments, you cannot display errors on your page if you are always redirecting.